# attr() method to src images

Tags: jquery, image, datepicker

I updated my code here:

```
<div class="selector">
    <h2 class="heading">Choose A Date</h2>
</div>

<img class="page-img" src="images/" width ="400px" height="600px" alt="front page here" title="image here">

<script type="text/javascript">

        // Datepicker
        $(document).ready(function (){$('.selector').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            constrainInput: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            maxDate: '0',
            yearRange: '-100y',
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            //$("input[name='yy-mm-dd']").val(dateText);
            $(".page-img").attr("images/", dateText + ".jpg"); 
       } 
    });
    });
```

I need to have the datepicker work so that when a date is selected, an image will be called and each date has it's own unique image. Someone advised me to use the jQuery attr() method and use it for src of image.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to achieve, based on what...input? How does the date (and where does the information about the date come from, in the mark-up) relate to the filename of the image that you want to use?

Comment: I have the images formatted to yy-mm-dd.jpeg like the dates, so 1941-12-08.jpeg should be shown for when the date 1941-12-08 (yy-mm-dd) has been chosen. The images are hosted in an images/ folder. Thanks

Comment: I've not worked with datepicker, so in what mark-up is the date string stored? One element, across several elements? Is it text, or in attributes? And can you add this information to the question itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this, I made an example for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/4xYfp/

Hope this helps

Comment: In this case I'm trying to get different images to be called when different dates are selected, matching the date formats to images with the same naming convention eg, 2012-03-11 to 2012-03-11.jpg and all the way back for many years. That's what I'm having difficulty with.

Answer (score 1):

To implement this, the following code may help:

Inside the datepicker you have an event onSelect. When someone is selecting a date you will change the image.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      alert("Selected date: " + dateText) // For exemple
      $("yourImage").attr("src", dateText + ".jpg") // Change the src for the "yourImage". 
   } 
});
```

However you will end up with the problem that 2012-03-08 is a date and the next is 2012-03-09 so you maybe only want to grab the day?

See the example:
http://jsbin.com/azunup/4/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Not sure I follow this part... "However you will end up with the problem that 2012-03-08 is a date and the next is 2012-03-09 so you maybe only want to grab the day?" Definitely I need the date not the day of the week to map to the images.

Comment: Ok so you have a unique image for each day for the next years. If so, it will be no problem. =)

Comment: Simon, that's good news. So does dateText fill in for the yy-mm-dd that's entered? "yourImage" for the Image class or id? What is 'src' referencing? Thanks

Comment: $("yourImage").attr("src", dateText + ".jpg")....When you say change the 'src' for the "yourImage", do you mean that's where I put the location of my images. I am probably missing something obvious here, but I'm still confused about how the different images can match the various dates chosen by users. Do I change "yourImage" and "src"?

Comment: $("yourImage") seraching for a image, in your case you should replace it to $(".image") cause you have an <img class="image">. attr("src", dateText + ".jpg")  change the attribute src (which is used to set the path to an image) to what "the date that the user selected" and add ".jpg" to the end. So for example if the user select "2012-03-10" the "src" for the img tag will be, "2012-03-10.jpg", if you need to go to a sub folder you have to add "../" before and so on. Play around with the demo in the last link that I gave you.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I am close but the images are still not showing when dates are clicked. The dateFormat is correct and matches the jpg names, 2012-03-11 matches 2012-03-11.jpg. I have the src changed to "images/" because they are in a subfolder called  "images" of where my files are located. The dateText is the date the user selects. Seems like the formula should work. Stuck on this.

Comment: If you right click on your image in the browser and go to properties and check what path is in your browser you maybe get a hint?

Comment: Thanks Simon. That was a very helpful example....$("#img").attr("src", "images/" + dateText + ".jpg");